# Get custom linq lambda for sorting

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Is it possible to return a custom lambda for linq sorting ?

```
// This is how I usually order stuff
quarable.OrderBy(d => d.Something);
// This is the signature of OrderBy I'm aiming for
IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
```

I want a result that would look something like this

```
static class SortingDevicesFiltersMethods {
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> GetLambda(this SortingDevicesFilters filter)
    {
        return (d => d.State);
    }
 }
```

And that can be called somehow like that

```
 quarable.OrderBy(someSortEnum.GetLambda());
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Does the code you wrote work then?

Comment: Since you call the extension method like a static method you have to pass the `SortingDevicesFilters` parameter

Comment: Sorry had a typo , no , the code does not work . Neither does it compile.

Comment: Then you need to explain what doesn't compile and what doesn't work, give us error messages etc.

Comment: It _might_ be possible by creating an [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/), but we have no idea what `SortingDevicesFilters` or how you want to use it to create dynamic filters.

Comment: @MakisMandrelas What about dynamic linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing missing from the code was a working signature.

```
Expression<Func<Device, Object >> GetLambda()
```

In my case , SortingDevicesFilters was an enum that - with a proper switch - returns the appropriate filters.

So it is possible to return a linq lambda from a function.

Comment: Seriously? Are you saying that your question was "*is it possible to return class instance from a function"* (because `Expression<…>` is a class like any other) and the answer is *"yes*" (obviously)?